# Why redis hash convert from ziplist to hashtable when key or value is large?

Tags: redis

There are two configs about data structure of hash in redis: `hash-max-ziplist-entries` and `hash-max-ziplist-value`.

It's easy to understand it should convert to hashtable when there are too many entries, as it will cost too much time for the get command.

But why it convert to hashtable when the value is large? As far as I can understand, as there is a "length" field in ziplist's entry, it shouldn't matter if one entry is 1 bit or 100 bits, it just need to move over the whole entry to get next one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to traverse both forward and backward, a `doubly linked list` has to save two pointers(i.e. 16 bytes on 64 bits machine) for each entry. If the entry data is small, say, 8 bytes, it will be very **memory inefficiency**: data is only 8 bytes, while the extra pointers cost 16 bytes.

In order to solve this problem, **`ziplist` uses two `variable length encoded` numbers to replace the two pointers, and save all entries in contiguous memory**. In this case, if all entry value is less than 64 bytes, these two `variable length encoded` numbers only cost 2 bytes (*please correct me, if I'm wrong*). This is very **memory efficient**. However, if the entry data is very large, say, 1024 bytes, this trick won't save too much memory, since the entry data costs more.

On the other hand, since `ziplist` saves all entries in contiguous memory in a compact way, **it has to do memory reallocation for almost every write operation**. That's very **CPU inefficient**. Also encoding and decoding those `variable length encoded` number cost CPU.

So if the entry data/value is small, you can use `ziplist` to achieve memory efficiency. However, if the data is large, you CANNOT get too much gain, while it costs you lots of CPU time.